как запарсить название файлов из папки
Короче говоря
у меня есть папка и в ней лежат файлы формата fb2 их много около 700к
как мне реализовать такое

автоматический вывод названий файлов из папки на польз. интерфейс
возможность скачивать эти файлы (сделать так что бы около названия была кнопка скачать и скачивался именно этот файл)
автоматическая подгрузка файлов, что бы не сразу все выводились
поиск, что бы можно было найти по названию нужный файл
и еще вопросик, а как то вообще можно из файла вытащить первую страницу и подставить как фото. И выташить из файла название книги и подставить в название (файлов fb2)

Как это реализовать ?
Может есть какие то готовые решения, был бы рад с ними ознакомится.
И вообще как это правильно называется, что бы понимать что мне гуглить и с чем мне надо ознакамливаться.

Вам нужен веб-сервер

это понятно что он нужен, а как все это написать кодом, вот это я не понимаю

Где лежат файлы относительно клиента? Скачивание файла - это просто ссылка на сам этот файл и все. Если вы автоматически отправите(даже последовательно) все 700к клиенту, вам пользователи спасибо не скажут. Поиск - это уже напрашивается база данных

Вот на вскидку, что вы описали, команде из опытного бэкэндера и фронтэндера делать это недели 2 не отвлекаясь ни на что другое(а то и больше). Описать все это в одном ответе врят ли получится. Да и что бы начать делать, надо определиться с серверной частью(на чем будет делаться). Самый расспростроненный вариант и доступный, это PHP+MySQL. Начните с создания таблицы книг и их описания. Потом научитесь выводить данные из таблицы, затем что бы фронт умел получать данные с бэка в виде списка ваших книг.

понятно что даже последовательно 700к файлов подгружать это много для пользователя, они будут подгружаться частями условно 50 пролистал и тебе подгрузит еще 50, а предыдущие выгрузит и так далее. не знаю на сколько это практично, но задумываю так

просто хотелось что бы направили что вообще нужно изучить, как +- будет выглядеть код для подгрузки или там для поиска. А то я даже не знаю как что называется и из за этого даже прогуглить не могу

Называется пагинация. Но вы опять же вопросы задаете из середины, а начинать надо с начала и определиться, на чем вы будете делать серверную часть. Научиться работать с БД(никто не ищет что то прямо в файлах из 700к штук - ну кроме крайней необходимости, когда другого варианта нет). Т.к. вы уже так или иначе работали с js, то можно выбрать node.js или начать изучать php - тут вам решать. Хостить сайт на php проще и есть у любого хостер-провайдера. Если для домашних целей, то node.js очень даже подойдет

а вот насчет книг, у меня вот они допустим хранятся на сервере и у меня есть json  и в нем получается должен быть путь до книги которую надо скачать, название книги и ее описание ? ну и айдишник. так ведь ?

Ну скорее всего. Все зависит от логики, которая будет заложена. Только вот если хотите все данные в 700к штук запихать в json - это тупиковая ветвь развития. Вам нужна база данных, в которой это все будет храниться. Из бд как раз будет приходить и ссылка на файл и описание и прочее. а json как формат обмена данными уже можно использовать для передачи информации клиенту
